# Gather boolean from repeating table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble finding the best way to achieve this. I'd like to solve it with just a select query if possible, but I'm not sure if it is solvable by just a select.

Customer Repeating Table:
- customer_id (PK)
- year (PK)
- code1
- code2

This is a repeating table, so a customer has multiple entries with their id number for the same year.

I need to some how gather a boolean or SELECT 'Y' to use as a flag where:

```
WHERE customer_id  = '1001'  
AND year = '2017'  
AND...
```

If there is any case for this customer for each of there code2
where (sum(code1 LIKE 'D%') <= sum(code1 LIKE 'R%')) then I need to return TRUE or 'Y'

#### Example Table

```
id      year    code1   code2

1001    2017    RE      AB
1001    2017    D2      AB
1001    2017    RW      BC
```

So here, it would return TRUE because for code2 that are AB,

```
sum(code1 LIKE 'D%') <= sum(code1 LIKE 'R%') = TRUE
```

I need to compare the sum of the code1's for all the different code2's that a customer has.

Comment: What do you mean by a *sum* of a string column? Do you mean a *count* of how many match the pattern?

Comment: Yes, the count of how many match the pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by PK in parentheses? Usually that means Primary Key, but you just said (and showed by example) that neither id not year, nor even the combination (id, year) is unique - so, what do you mean by PK?  THEN: WHERE would you like to return TRUE (really, 'TRUE' as a string since Oracle does not have Boolean data type) - what is the output going to look like? Return all the original rows, with an added column with TRUE/FALSE values?  THEN: Can code2 be NULL, and if so, how should that be handled?

Comment: Ignore the PK. I did mean primary key, but that was an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to toss some `CASE` statements at this and aggregate:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Sum(CASE WHEN code1 LIKE 'D%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <= Sum(CASE WHEN code1 LIKE 'R%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS yourtest
FROM yourTable
WHERE id=1001 AND year=2017
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I need to ensure that the customer doesn't have a different code2 that wouldn't satisfy those same conditions. Say my example had more entries for a different code2 where that statement would return false.

Comment: Even if the statement gathered multiple booleans and I could just do an exist to see if a false exists in the selection, that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need. I created more test data in the WITH clause (which is only for testing, you don't need it for your actual data). I changed the column name from `yr` to `year` since **year** is an Oracle keyword, which shouldn't be used as table or column name.

I create an initial flag, `FLAG1`, for each `code2` value - used to then compute the final flag, `FLAG2`, for each `(id, yr)` combination. In my query I show both flags, just so you can see how this works; you probably need only `FLAG2`.

And it is not really clear what output you require; I assumed you just wanted an additional flag to complement the input data. If you need something else, perhaps you can adapt it yourself. If you need to add a specific `id` and specific year, you can do so by adding a `WHERE` clause to the subquery (in which case you can clean up the analytic functions by removing `id` and `yr` from the `PARTITION BY` clause).

```
with
  inputs ( id, yr, code1, code2 ) as (
    select 1001, 2017, 'RE', 'AB' from dual union all
    select 1001, 2017, 'D2', 'AB' from dual union all
    select 1001, 2017, 'RW', 'BC' from dual union all
    select 1004, 2015, 'RE', 'ZZ' from dual union all
    select 1004, 2015, 'DW', 'XX' from dual union all
    select 1004, 2016, 'RX', 'ZZ' from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line. Use your actual table and column names.
select id, yr, code1, code2, flag1,
       case count(case flag1 when 'FALSE' then 1 end)
                                            over (partition by id, yr)
            when 0 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as flag2
from   (       
         select id, yr, code1, code2,
                case when count(case when code1 like 'D%' then 1 end) 
                                            over (partition by id, yr, code2)
                          <=
                          count(case when code1 like 'R%' then 1 end)
                                            over (partition by id, yr, code2)
                     then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as flag1
         from   inputs
       )
;

        ID         YR CODE1 CODE2 FLAG1 FLAG2
---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----- -----
      1001       2017 RE    AB    TRUE  TRUE 
      1001       2017 D2    AB    TRUE  TRUE 
      1001       2017 RW    BC    TRUE  TRUE 
      1004       2015 DW    XX    FALSE FALSE
      1004       2015 RE    ZZ    TRUE  FALSE
      1004       2016 RX    ZZ    TRUE  TRUE
```